# creating a deep voice with a sample

Tags: sound-design, sampling, sample, sampler

Hey guys just trying to figure out how to go about producing that deep voice heard in tech house alot these days, darker dance music in general.  It just doesnt seem to me that they are solely lowering the pitch.  Is it a vocoder that is being used?

Below is an example of what I mean.  Can really here it at 3:47

The solution to this doesnt have t be this song exactly as an example Id just like to know how to go about creating it in general terms so that I can create my own sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the vocoder on that, maybe autotune, i think i hear autotune on the lower end of that voice shot. Try autotune and then add a vocoder in to see if it lines up. The keys right after the shot are perfectly aligned in terms of sound waves, whatever they did to that chord stab they did to the vocals.

Comment: trying this out now,  Ide really like to know how they made that chord stab as well great sound

Comment: Seems like Im getting close,  Im using logics built in pitch correctors and vocal transformers.   Any plugins that you enjoy using?  Whats your take on level of pitch shift and vocoder settings to make it sound clean?

Comment: You really have to just fiddle with it until you get the desired sound. A knowledge of audio engineering/recording helps. Perhaps youtube vids on vocoders and autotune will help?